# Karma runner with Test Coverage in a TypeScript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, karma-runner, istanbul

I am working on a React/TypeScript application that uses Karma test runner and we would like to have test coverage reports.

As a bundler we use Webpack so Karma config looks like this (I removed insignificant lines):

```
config.set({
    basePath: 'src',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
    files: [
        {pattern: 'src/my.ts'},
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'src/my.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap', 'coverage'],
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    webpack: {
        module: webpackConfig.module,
        resolve: webpackConfig.resolve,
        plugins: [
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: null,
                test: /\.(ts|tsx|js)($|\?)/i
            })
        ]
    },
});
```

The problem is that after execution in my report I get transpiled file, not the original TypeSctipt file.

It looks like it shows coverage (unsuded code is red, etc) but in transpiled form it is useless.

**How can I fix that?**

I tried to use `karma-remap-istanbul` but I get an error message `Could not find source map for: src/my.ts`.

PS: I know about `karma-typescript` but I need to make it work with current transpiling done with `webpack`, it looks like it will take a lot of effort to change everything to make it work with karma-typescript.